# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I'm studying Principles and Practices using C++ and am having issues linking to the proper architecture I'm currently using an Apple computer, my compiler is gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00), 
when I

```
file /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

/usr/lib/libffi.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures                                                                                                                                         
/usr/lib/libffi.dylib (for architecture x86_64):        Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64                                                                                              
/usr/lib/libffi.dylib (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

in which I have both architectures/libraries available here's what I'm using to compile my program

```
    g++ -Wall chapter.12.3.cpp -o chapter.12.3 


In file included from GUI.h:11,                                                                                                                                                                             
                 from Simple_window.h:10,                                                                                                                                                                   
                 from chapter.12.3.cpp:7:                                                                                                                                                                   
Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Color::Color(Graph_lib::Color::Color_type)’:                                                                                                                            
Graph.h:56: warning: ‘Graph_lib::Color::c’ will be initialized after                                                                                                                                        
Graph.h:55: warning:   ‘char Graph_lib::Color::v’                                                                                                                                                           
Graph.h:45: warning:   when initialized here                                                                                                                                                                
Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Color::Color(Graph_lib::Color::Color_type, Graph_lib::Color::Transparency)’:                                                                                            
Graph.h:56: warning: ‘Graph_lib::Color::c’ will be initialized after                                                                                                                                        
Graph.h:55: warning:   ‘char Graph_lib::Color::v’                                                                                                                                                           
Graph.h:46: warning:   when initialized here                                                                                                                                                                
Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Color::Color(int)’:                                                                                                                                                     
Graph.h:56: warning: ‘Graph_lib::Color::c’ will be initialized after                                                                                                                                        
Graph.h:55: warning:   ‘char Graph_lib::Color::v’                                                                                                                                                           
Graph.h:47: warning:   when initialized here                                                                                                                                                                
Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Color::Color(Graph_lib::Color::Transparency)’:                                                                                                                          
Graph.h:56: warning: ‘Graph_lib::Color::c’ will be initialized after                                                                                                                                        
Graph.h:55: warning:   ‘char Graph_lib::Color::v’                                                                                                                                                           
Graph.h:48: warning:   when initialized here                                                                                                                                                                
Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle(Point, int, int)’:                                                                                                                                 
Graph.h:211: warning: ‘Graph_lib::Rectangle::w’ will be initialized after                                                                                                                                   
Graph.h:210: warning:   ‘int Graph_lib::Rectangle::h’                                                                                                                                                       
Graph.h:194: warning:   when initialized here                                                                                                                                                               
Graph.h: In constructor ‘Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle(Point, Point)’:                                                                                                                                    
Graph.h:211: warning: ‘Graph_lib::Rectangle::w’ will be initialized after                                                                                                                                   
Graph.h:210: warning:   ‘int Graph_lib::Rectangle::h’                                                                                                                                                       
Graph.h:200: warning:   when initialized here                                                                                                                                                               
In file included from Simple_window.h:10,                                                                                                                                                                   
                 from chapter.12.3.cpp:7:                                                                                                                                                                   
GUI.h: In member function ‘virtual void Graph_lib::Menu::show()’:                                                                                                                                           
GUI.h:107: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions                                                                                                                              
GUI.h: In member function ‘virtual void Graph_lib::Menu::hide()’:                                                                                                                                           
GUI.h:112: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions                                                                                                                              
GUI.h: In member function ‘virtual void Graph_lib::Menu::move(int, int)’:                                                                                                                                   
GUI.h:117: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions                                                                                                                              
Graph.h: In destructor ‘Graph_lib::Vector_ref<T>::~Vector_ref() [with T = Graph_lib::Button]’:                                                                                                              
GUI.h:96:   instantiated from here                                                                                                                                                                          
Graph.h:130: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions                                                                                                                            
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:                                                                                                                                                                  
  "Simple_window::Simple_window(Point, int, int, String const&)", referenced from:                                                                                                                          
      _main in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                                   
  "Graph_lib::Polygon::add(Point)", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                        
      _main in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                                   
  "Simple_window::wait_for_button()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                      
      _main in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                                   
  "Graph_lib::Shape::Shape()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                             
      Graph_lib::Open_polyline::Open_polyline()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Open_polyline", referenced from:  
Graph_lib::Open_polyline::Open_polyline()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Open_polyline", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                   
      Graph_lib::Open_polyline::Open_polyline()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                
      Graph_lib::Open_polyline::~Open_polyline()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                               
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.                                                                                                      
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Closed_polyline", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                 
      Graph_lib::Closed_polyline::Closed_polyline()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                            
      Graph_lib::Closed_polyline::~Closed_polyline()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                           
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.                                                                                                      
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Polygon", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                         
      Graph_lib::Polygon::Polygon()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                            
      Graph_lib::Polygon::~Polygon()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                           
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.                                                                                                      
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Shape", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                           
      Graph_lib::Shape::~Shape()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                               
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.                                                                                                      
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Button", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                          
      Graph_lib::Button::~Button()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                             
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.                                                                                                      
  "vtable for Graph_lib::Window", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                          
      Graph_lib::Window::~Window()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                             
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.                                                                                                      
  "Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                               
      Graph_lib::Window::~Window()in ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                             
  "Graph_lib::Window::draw()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                             
      vtable for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                 
  "Fl_Window::handle(int)", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                                
      vtable for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                 
  "Fl_Window::resize(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                 
      vtable for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                 
  "Fl_Window::show()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                                     
      vtable for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                 
  "Fl_Window::hide()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                                     
      vtable for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                 
  "Fl_Window::flush()", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                                    
      vtable for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                                 
  "typeinfo for Graph_lib::Window", referenced from:                                                                                                                                                        
      typeinfo for Simple_windowin ccarbqNp.o                                                                                                                                                               
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64                                                                                                                                                             
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status                                                                                                                                                                         

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri Oct 21 12:48:23
```

it seems as though the library that I'm using libbookgui.a isn't compiled to the proper architecture but I could be incorrect.

when I check what the architecture the lib file is built I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/libbookgui.a: current ar archive random library
```

Comment: yes, but gcc is saying the problem is in the object files already compiled

Comment: There is no way to determine what is going on here without more information.  Try reducing to to a trivial code example and giving us the compile and link commands that you are using to build and link.

Comment: what information is needed please explain, from what I'm seeing gcc is mostly giving warnings the main problem I see is it not finding the proper architecture which is in the libbookgui.a lib I've used the make file which comes from the creators site but when I use it all I get is gcc complaining about the library not being built for the proper architecture.

Comment: Where are SimpleWindow, GraphLib::* and Fl_Window defined?

Comment: **here's the answer I wasn't linking the Cocoa framework**                       `g++ -Wall -I/directory/to/headerfiles -L/directory/to/libraryfiles -lbookgui -lstdc++ -lfltk -lfltk_images -lfltk_jpeg -framework Cocoa`